# Is there any good free (audio) converter which can convert to M4C?

Tags: audio, conversion

I tried one, the first result in Google, but on whatever reason it does not give me the option to convert to M4C. Maybe it's only **from** M4C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Free Audio Converter](http://free-audio-converter.uptodown.com/en). But in case if you want to convert mp3 you'll need to convert mp3 to aac, and then aac to m4c.

Comment: yeah this was the one i downloaded before. thanks for saying that i first have to convert it to aac.

Comment: it does not work. I first convert it to AAC, and then i select the AAC file, but it does not give me the m4c option, just (MP3,M4A,AAC,WAV,WMA,OGG) Do i have to do some special thing or so?

Comment: U do have m4c codex, right?